# Android app list structure, and finding Context from a Global class

Tags: android, json, android-fragments

I have two questions.

Suppose I'm creating an android app with three types of screens:

first, a series of 3 tabs that display information in a list. The type of information determines which tab(s) it's displayed in.

[image: 3-tabbed screen]

[image: Item info]

[image: Item addition]

Second, a screen with in-depth detail about a selected list item.

And third, a screen where you can add a list item, which will populate the appropriate list.

What would be a good structure for this program? Right now what I have is a Global class (extends Application) that keeps track of the lists and imports them from a JSON file, an Activity (and accompanying Fragment) for each of the three screens above, and a separate Fragment for the individual tabs.

However, I'm finding that importing the JSON file in the Globals class requires Context that I can't figure out how to get. Before I go any farther, is this a good structure?

And if so, how can I get context in a Global class?

I'm working in Android Studio 3.

Comment: "Right now what I have is a Global class (extends Application) ... in the Globals class requires Context that I can't figure out how to get" –
 `Application` is a `Context`. "Before I go any farther, is this a good structure?" – That's opinion-based, and therefore off-topic here. Some users like using an `Application` as a "global" data store. Others do not.

Comment: "Application is a Context."
When I call getApplicationContext() from the constructor class, I get a nullpointerexception. Should I be doing this another way, or at another point?

Comment: First, an `Application` subclass should not have any explicitly defined constructors. Do your initializations in `onCreate()`. Second, there's no need to call `getApplicationContext()`. Just use `this`.

Comment: Excellent, thank you. That seems to have solved my problem! Would you like to add it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Application` is a `Context`. That is, you can just use the current instance – `this` – wherever you need a `Context`. (There's no need to call `getApplicationContext()`.)

However, the backing `Context` will not be properly initialized and attached yet in an `Application`'s constructor. An `Application` is actually a `ContextWrapper`, which is a `Context` subclass that delegates all method calls to a `Context` field that is created and set by the system upon launch. This means that you cannot call any `Context` methods in the constructor, as it will still be null there.

As with the `Activity` and `Service` classes, though, `Application`s generally should not have any explicitly defined constructors anyway. Any initialization that needs to be done can be performed in its `onCreate()` method. The `Context` field will have been set by then.